# migrating from CAS server 4.0.0 to CAS 5.3.0

Tags: ldap, cas

i want to upgrade our CAS server from 4.0.0 to 5.3.0
how to import my cas setting for example my ldap url to the new CAS version?
in CAS 5.3.0 i can not see any deployerConfigContext.xml and cas.properties files
and it seems that the parametrs are totaly different
thank you

Comment: Take a look on [ldap authentication](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html#ldap-authenticationl). You will have more chances to get an appropriate answer if you ask  specific things. E.g what customization have you performed over default `deployerConfigContext.xml `?

Comment: it's a part of my deployerConfigContext.xml:<bean id="authenticator" class="org.ldaptive.auth.Authenticator"
          c:resolver-ref="dnResolver"
          c:handler-ref="authHandler" />

   <bean id="dnResolver"
          class="org.ldaptive.auth.FormatDnResolver"
          c:format="cn=%s,ou=org1,${ldap.authn.baseDn}" />

    <bean id="authHandler" class="org.ldaptive.auth.PooledBindAuthenticationHandler"
          p:connectionFactory-ref="pooledLdapConnectionFactory" />

Comment: and my main problem is that i do not HAVE any cas.properties file to put these settings in!

Comment: I advise you to look [official docs](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Maven-Overlay-Installation.html). It contains all information you search. Use cas-overlay-tempalte, follow instructions and add your own `cas.properties` on correct path inside overlay.